# Connect to SharePoint using Browser Authentication

Tags: python, sharepoint

I want to connect to SharePoint using the Browser Authentication method. Do you know any library and sample code for this? Thanks.

Pnp-Powershell: I want like this but on Python. The "-Interactive" parameter will open the Browser for authentication the login

```
$site_url = "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/site_url"
Connect-PnpOnline -Url $site_url -Interactive
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Office365-Rest-Python-Client library to access to SharePoint documents.
https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client

Comment: Here are some examples about file operations:https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/tree/master/examples/sharepoint/files

Comment: Is this library as reliable as PnP?